# Domain Access And Subfolders

Tags: domain-access, subsites

This has indeed been asked somewhere but still no answer. Is there a way to have domain access provide links like example.com/site1 instead of side1.example.com Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are looking for the [Subfolders Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subfolders_domain) module.

> Create and configuring easily the hierarchy Subdirectory multi-site for your Drupal multi site from one installation and a single shared database. This module allows you to add new subdomains directories or management of subdomains directories without changing/adding any file configuration (such .htaccess, sites.php, Alias in Apache config file, ...)

Comment: Thanks I have tried it, but I keep getting page not found errors on local-host. Even tried it on a web-host still nothing...maybe there was something wrong with my configuration or it doesn't work on shared hosting.